# Map with dates as key doesn't retrieve items correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a map which will be something of the type:
key: date -> values: list of objects

For that purpose I've got the following piece of code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let allPredictions = listAllPredictions();
    this.predictions = new Map();

    for (let i = 0; i<allPredictions.length; i++) {
        let prediction = allPredictions[i];

        if (!this.predictions.has(prediction.tsPredictionFor)){
            this.predictions.set(prediction.tsPredictionFor, []);
        }

        let predictionsForDate = this.predictions.get(prediction.tsPredictionFor);
        predictionsForDate.push(prediction);
    }
    let d = new Date(2019, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    console.log('Prediction for date ' + d + ': ' + this.predictions.get(d));
    console.log('All predictions: ')
    console.log(this.predictions)

    //this.setState({activePredictions: listActivePredictions()})
}
```

What doesn't seem to work is that the map cannot compare 2 dates correctly. I noticed that the `.has` function returns false all the time, even though there are entries with same date.

These are the logs:
[image: logs]

As you can see, the following indices have the same date: 0 and 3, 1 and 4, 2 and 5, but for some reason the map cannot detect this, so for every entry it creates a new list (as you can see: Array(1)).

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Your mapping Object's, all objects are going to be unique,.. Maybe use the value of `.getTime()` as the key instead.

Comment: Hmm, but two times can overlap from different days. Is there a method for datetime?

Comment: `getTime()` is a number representing a DateTime, not just a time.

Comment: Javascript surely is a magical language. thanks a lot

Comment: Can also use any string representation of the date object as keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date` object does not override the `===` operator, meaning that what is going to be compared is whether or not they have the same reference.

As a simple example, take the following code :

```js
console.log(new Date() === new Date())
```

This is always going to return false no matter what because both created objects have a different reference.

However, you can use the string generated by formatting them as a key :

```js
console.log((new Date()).getTime() === (new Date()).getTime())
```